# How to find Fourier series for $f = \arctan\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The problem is as follows

> Use rectangular coordinates for the disk $\Bbb D = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le 1\}$, and
> define a function $u(x,y)=\arctan(\frac{y}{1+x})$
>
> (a)Show that $u$ is constant on straight line segments through $(-1,0)$ hence evaluate $f(\theta)=\lim_{r \to 1-}u(r\cos\theta, r\cos\theta$)

Attempt : (a) suppose $y=m(x+1)$

$$ u(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{m(x+1)}{x+1}\right)=\arctan(m)$$

so $u$ is constant

Now consider
$$f(\theta)=\lim_{r \to 1-}u(r \cos\theta, r \cos\theta) = \lim_{r \to 1-} \arctan\left(\frac{r \sin\theta}{1 + r \cos\theta} \right) = \arctan \left(\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}\right)$$

for $-\pi\lt \theta \lt \pi$

$$ \arctan\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{2 \cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}}\right) = \arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right)\right)=\frac{\theta}{2}$$ $QED$

Is this correct? But Why do I show $u$ is constant to evaluate $f(\theta)$?

Comment: You showed u is constantly equal to the slope of the line. In polar coordinates, $\tan{\theta} = m$

Comment: @DaveNine Thank  you for help. I understood!